# How to display two constructed images separately in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

Following codes construct 2 CT images, and then follows the reconstruction process,

```
%reconstruction of an phantom
img = phantom(256) % generate the phantom
maxvalimg=max(max(img)) %obtain maximum value of 2D array
minvalimg=min(min(img)) %obtain minimum value of 2d array
imshow(img,[minvalimg,maxvalimg]); %display the generated image

theta = 0:359 % generate angle vector
R = radon(img, theta) % generate the sin construction 
maxvalR=max(max(R))
minvalR=min(min(R))
imshow(R,[minvalR,maxvalR]); % display the image
```

As the code runs, first image override the second image, how can i separately obtain those two images, ( of course i can run codes block separately), but i need to run them in single run, then need to obtain the constructed images)

Comment: So you need to add `figure(1)` before the first `imshow` and `figure(2)` before the second `imshow`

Comment: or simply `figure`

Comment: You can also use subplot, or plot them together by `imshow([img,R],[])` but you loose control of the min-max with this last one and may not work for oyu, as the first thing is a CT image, the second just the sinogram

Comment: Thanks for the comments, codes are still under development, few more need to be added to perform noise filtration.

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain"? Do you want to just display them, or to save them as e.g. `.png` files?

Comment: Yes display separately! Without over written